# Gerar um array em função de outro sem gargalos

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte array de objectos:

```
[
   { 
      id: "1", 
      name: "ProdutoA",
      categorias: [
          {idCat: 1, name: "CategoriaA"},
          {idCat: 2, name: "CategoriaB"}
      ] 
   },
   { 
      id: "2", 
      name: "ProdutoB",
      categorias: [
          {idCat: 1, name: "CategoriaA"}
      ] 
   }
]
```

A partir desse array de objectos, preciso gerar outro array com a seguinte estrutura:

```
[
   {idCat: 1, name: "CategoriaA", products: ["ProdutoA","ProdutoB"]},
   {idCat: 2, name: "CategoriaB", products: ["ProdutoA"]}
]
```

Não sei como fazer isso utilizando as melhores práticas de JavaScript, apenas utilizando o ciclo `for`, mas não sei se será performático quando o  primeiro array for muito grande.

Como gerar o segundo array em função do primeiro?

**Observação**: O array de objetos inicial sempre estará consistente e é produzido desta forma por meio de um framework. Logo, todos os elementos com um mesmo `idCat` terão sempre o mesmo `name`, e portanto não é necessário se preocupar com um caso hipotético aonde dois elementos com um mesmo `idCat` tenham `name`s diferentes.

Comment: você poderia definir muito grande? por exemplo, um array com 1000 posições pode ser grande para um humano processar visualmente, mas para um computador ele é pequeno.

Comment: Mas já que a sua ideia é criar um novo array com base no primeiro, então o ideal é usar [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) no lugar do for.

Comment: E o que deveria acontecer caso se tenha `{categoris : [ {idCat: 1, name : 'CategoriaA'}]}` e outro com `{categoris : [ {idCat: 1, name : 'CategoriaB'}]}`?

Comment: @TobyMosque imagine que seja 1000 posições, mas em "categorias" tenho 10 registros, são 10mil registros processados, o problema é que tenho que pecorrer o novo array todo toda vez que quero verificar se a categoria já existe.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert isso não pode ocorrer, não há categorias diferentes com o mesmo ID, pelo menos foi o que você usou como exemplo, repare que "CategoriaA" tem o mesmo "idCat" que "CategoriaB".

Comment: @FilipeMoraes estão você concorda que `name` é irrelevante e `idCat` quem deveria apontar para a categoria respectiva?

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Acho que o que o Guilherme quer dizer é que sua estrutura "viola a terceira forma normal" hehe. Pois se em `categorias` você já tem `idCat` e `nome`, por que repetir os mesmos parâmetros em cada produto, por que não ter somente uma lista de IDs no produto? Eu entendo que talvez esses dados estejam sendo gerados por uma ferramenta, e por isso não possam ser mudados, então nesse caso podemos assumir que uma solução não precisa se preocupar com isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert sim, é isso, mas o nome tem que ser incluído no novo array, mas a ligação é feita através do idCat.

Comment: @mgibsonbr sim, o primeiro array é gerado por uma framework, o segundo array é que eu preciso, por isso a necessidade de transforma-lo.

Comment: P.S. A biblioteca underscore.js possui [um método `groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) que poderia te ajudar com isso, mas a saída que ela gera é outra (teria de ser adaptada), e de todo modo não compensa incluir uma biblioteca só pra usar uma função, em especial quando se busca eficiência. Melhor fazer à mão mesmo...

Comment: Em resumo você quer percorrer todo o `array verificando quais produtos estão vinculado com cada `idCat`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert exacto, conforme o exemplo que postei.

Comment: @mgibsonbr então, minha duvida é como fazer isso a mão sem que o código fique pesado, essa é a minha preocupação! Sei fazer utilizando apenas o ciclo FOR.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Não acho que usando o `for` seja ruim, em especial se a sua lógica estiver correta. Escrevi uma resposta usando `forEach`, mas seria a mesma coisa (e até mais eficiente, acho) usando `for`s, o que importa é que o número de operações executado - até onde meu conhecimento vai - é mínimo, dificilmente você conseguiria uma solução mais eficiente...

Comment: Esta pergunta está na fila de fechamento como "*não está clara o suficiente*". Para mim ela parece ser clara, então vou votar em "**Deixar aberta**". Alguém aí poderia explicar o motivo de querer fechá-la?

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu votei, por causa no 3,5,6,7,8 comentários que só então se pode obter o resultado conforme o esperado, sem considerar isto, e resposta esperada não seria possível. Então era melhor salientá-los na pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Ok, editei a pergunta para tentar cobrir esse caso com base no que está escrito nos comentários.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Olhando para o exemplo que dei, todas as perguntas 3,5,6,7 e 8 são respondidas. No exemplo é possível ver que a ligação é pelo idCat e que o nome da categoria não se repete. A pergunta está clara, como transformar um array A em um array B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como os IDs das categorias são simples números, um objeto mapeando ID para estrutura deve ser suficiente:

```js
function converter(produtos) {
  var map = {};
  
  produtos.forEach(function(produto) {
      produto.categorias.forEach(function(cat) {
          if ( !map[cat.idCat] )
              map[cat.idCat] = { idCat:cat.idCat, name:cat.name, products:[] };
          map[cat.idCat].products.push(produto.name);
      });
  });
  
  var ret = [];
  for ( var p in map )
    ret.push(map[p]);
  // Opcional: ordena o retorno
  return ret;
}

var entrada = [
   { 
      id: "1", 
      name: "ProdutoA",
      categorias: [
          {idCat: 1, name: "CategoriaA"},
          {idCat: 2, name: "CategoriaB"}
      ] 
   },
   { 
      id: "2", 
      name: "ProdutoB",
      categorias: [
          {idCat: 1, name: "CategoriaA"}
      ] 
   }
];
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(converter(entrada), null, 4) + "<pre>";
```

Comment: Foi mais rápido e ainda ficou melhor que a que eu estava pensando. +1

Answer (score 1):

Olha, acho que a melhor maneira, é usar um pouco de Prototype e criar duas listas (Produtos e Categoria) e criar referencias entre elas.

```js
var estrutura = [
  { 
    id: "1", 
    name: "ProdutoA",
    categorias: [
      {idCat: 1, name: "CategoriaA"},
      {idCat: 2, name: "CategoriaB"}
    ] 
  },
  { 
    id: "2", 
    name: "ProdutoB",
    categorias: [
      {idCat: 1, name: "CategoriaA"}
    ] 
  }
];

var produtos = {};
var categorias = {};

var Produto = function (item) {
  this.id = item.id;
  this.name = item.name;
  this.categorias = [];
}

var Categoria = function (subitem) {
  this.idCat = subitem.idCat;
  this.name = subitem.name;
  this.produtos = [];
}

estrutura.forEach(function (item, indice) {
  var produto = new Produto(item);
  produtos[item.id] = produto;

  item.categorias.forEach(function (subitem, indice) {
    var categoria = categorias[subitem.idCat];
    if (!categoria) {
      categoria = new Categoria(subitem);
      categorias[subitem.idCat] = categoria;
    }
    categoria.produtos.push(produto);
    produto.categorias.push(categoria);
  });
});

console.log(categorias, produtos);
```

neste caso, você poderá acessar o produto ou categoria pelo ID:

```
var produto = produtos[1]; //retorna o ProdutoA;
var categoria = categoria[1]; //retorna a CategoriaA;
```

assim como poder navegar dentro das propriedades:

```
var irmaos = produtos[2].categorias[1].produtos; //todos os produtos da categoriaA
```